# Magento 2 CMS 404 error

Tags: magento2

we are in the process of updating our humble little Magento 1.7 shop to the latest version 2.3

It is a multi-language store and we have succesfully migrated all customers and all categories and products. Within the categories and also in the account pages etc. the chosen template works and all seems well.

BUT one thing is driving us crazy now for days and that is the cms start page.

The content section on our home page is returning 404, "Whoops our bad..." all the time. We have tried nearly everything we could find in the net:

- setting "Single Store Mod" to "No"
- checking the url_rewrite table with an empty request_path value (noe is there)
- setting for ofweb/default/cms_home_page is there and set ok and for scope_id = 0
- adding the correct relationships in cms_page_store
- setting the "Default Web URL" to cms
- having the home page selected as "Homepage"

If we browse directly to the CMS page it works fine, but when we view it on our homepage we always get the 404 error.

As said, all store views and subcategories are working fine, only this cms main page is not :/

Does anyone maybe have a clue what is going wrong and how we could possibly get the start page running?

We would be super glad for any hint on this.

Best regards from Germany

Comment: Try php bin/magento set:upgrade & php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hint. We have tried this but unfortunately after "bin/magento set:upgrade" we only get: "Nothing to import." and "php bin/magento cache:clean" is running through smoothly.